# VLOOKUP #N/A error

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm wondering what I have done wrong to get the #N/A error

I would like to have `K21` show the Agent's name that worked on the ticket appeared in `K20`. I have the Agent names listed in `B3:B18`.

Columns have: `C` Total, `D` type and `E` subtotal.

Ticket numbers get logged from column `F3`, `G`, `H` and so on for each agent

`K20` has `=MIN(F3:XFD18)` to determine the oldest ticket.

`K21` has `=VLOOKUP($K$20,B2:G18,3,FALSE)`  to show the Agent's name that logged the oldest ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about what you're asking but it sounds like you might be using the formula wrong. If you are wanting to return the agent's name from the oldest ticket make sure your columns are in the correct order (a-lookup value,b-agent name,c-other variable). 
Using that format you can try `K21=VLOOKUP($K$20,A2:B18,2,FALSE)` 
----where `A2:A18` has the value you are looking up and 2 is the second column (B) and has the agent's name.

Comment: thanks for the response, 

I have tried using that Approach

I also tried putting values on the cells on Column A and tried K21=VLOOKUP($K$20,A2:B18,1,FALSE) just to so see if it's going to give results. but it behave diferently.

the result it came back is frome a different row
also I don't if merge cells has something to do with it as well as each Agents occupied 2 cells B2+B3, b4+b5 and so on.

the result is It gave back was 0 if I use TRUE

Comment: is there way to get the that is in first column?

Answer (score 0):

With Agents names listed in ColumnB the ticket will not be found in that column.